# How can I add non-model fields to a simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I need to add a non-model field to a `simple_form`. Several actually. But I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `parameter_id_17' for #<ReportDefinition:0x007fdc22aad088>):
```

This is within a `fields_for` block. I know it's undefined for the model I'm trying to use it for. I was hoping I could still use `simple_form` and not have to resort to the Rails native tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you model you can add:

```
attr_accessor :something, :something_else
```

Comment: Excellent. I have a whole bunch of these parameters, so I wrapped the above in a "50.times do" loop. Works perfectly!